# Java Unreported Exception while using JFileChooser

Tags: java, exception, jfilechooser

```
public FileReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
    //create fileChooser
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    //open fileChooser
    int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
    try {
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
}
```

I'm writing a program to read a text file and puts it into an array of Strings (words). This is just the file reader for the program, and it's giving me an error when I try to call the method from another part of the code. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated; its probably a simple fix and I just can't seem to find it.

Here's the error:

> unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: On which line does that occur?

Comment: it actually occurs when i call method elsewhere but this is the problematic code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting bit by checked exceptions rather hard here.  The main thing is that `FileNotFoundException` is checked, and it must either:

- be caught in a `try...catch` statement at its point of use, or
- declared to be thrown via the `throws` declaration in the method's signature.

You *do not* generally want to do both of those at the same time, which you are right now.

As further advice, you also don't want to do either of these:

- throw an exception in the constructor
- not do anything with a caught exception

So my personal advice would be to catch the exception and deal with it...

```
public FileReader()  {
    //create fileChooser
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    //open fileChooser
    int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
    try {
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

...but unless I'm looking at the wrong libraries, [I don't see ***anywhere*** where a `FileNotFoundException` is even *thrown* on `JFileChooser`!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)  That'd make your code simple enough - don't bother* with the `try...catch` at that point.

<sup>*: You'd actually *have* to remove it since it's a compilation error to catch a checked exception that's never thrown.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the constructor as throwing a checked exception:

```
public FileReader() throws FileNotFoundException
```

Anywhere you call this constructor, you must either declare it thrown from that method, e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  new FileReader();
}
```

or catch it and handle it, e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    new FileReader();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle e.
  }
}
```

or, if nothing in `FileReader()` throws an uncaught `FileNotFoundException` (like in your code, where the `FileNotFoundException` is caught and swallowed), remove the `throws FileNotFoundException` from `FileReader()`, allowing e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new FileReader();
}
```